# matching cells in two sheets and populating second sheet with matched first sheet data

Tags: excel

my problem is that I have two excel sheets one with CompanyA and other details like phone number and address etc, the other sheet has CompanyA  and contact name. What I would like to do is to match the company name from sheet 1 to sheet two and enter the address and phone number details beside the contact details. Can this be done?

Comment: [This link](http://howtovlookupinexcel.com/vlookup-between-two-workbooks) uses VLOOKUP to solve a problem very similar to yours

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do using the VLOOKUP function.

Select the cell on the sheet where you want to add data and type "=VLOOKUP(".  You will notice that it pops up with the parameters for that function:

[image: VLOOKUP function]

For the first parameter lookup_value, click on "Contact Name" (or whatever value you plan to use to look up on), then press comma.

For the second parameter table_array, select the other sheet, and highlight the whole of the data table.  Notice in the function bar it says "Contacts!A1:C3".  The exclamation mark is how we reference other sheets in excel.

[image: First and second parameters]

The third parameter "col_index_num" is the number of the column you are looking up.  So in my example, 2 = "Phone Number".  The fourth parameter can be left off, but it tells Excel whether to find an approximate match.

[image: Second parameter]

Voila!